# Error getting ADC input

Tags: c++, controller, arm, embedded, cortex-m

I am using a Cortex-M3 based board. It is the first time I am programming this kind of board, so I don't know how to read the libraries and make it "happen".

This board comes with a temperature sensor, and I am trying to use the adc lib for reading.

My code:

```
#include <adc.h>
#include <gpio.h>

using namespace EPOS;
//const NIC::Protocol NIC_PROTOCOL = 42;

ADC * temperature;

int main()
{
   temperature = new ADC( 0xE, 0x2, 0x3);
   //    printf("&temperature"); 

   return 0;
}
```

**The library**

```
// EPOS ARM Cortex-M Analog to Digital Converter (ADC) Mediator Declarations

#include <system/config.h>
#if !defined(__cortex_adc_h_) && defined(__ADC_H)
#define __cortex_adc_h_

#include <adc.h>
#include <machine.h>

__BEGIN_SYS

class ADC: private ADC_Common, private Machine_Model
{
public:
    enum Channel {
        SINGLE_ENDED_ADC0 = 0,
        SINGLE_ENDED_ADC1 = 1,
        SINGLE_ENDED_ADC2 = 2,
        SINGLE_ENDED_ADC3 = 3,
        SINGLE_ENDED_ADC4 = 4,
        SINGLE_ENDED_ADC5 = 5,
        SINGLE_ENDED_ADC6 = 6,
        SINGLE_ENDED_ADC7 = 7,
        DIFF8             = 8,
        DIFF9             = 9,
        DIFF10            = 10,
        DIFF11            = 11,
        GND               = 12,
        TEMPERATURE       = 14,
        AVDD5_3           = 15,
    };

    enum Reference {
        INTERNAL_REF   = 0,
        EXTERNAL_REF   = 1, // External reference on AIN7 pin
        SYSTEM_REF     = 2,
        EXTERNAL_DIFF  = 3
    };

    enum Resolution {
        BITS_7  = 0, //  7 bits resolution, 64  decimation rate
        BITS_9  = 1, //  9 bits resolution, 128 decimation rate
        BITS_10 = 2, // 10 bits resolution, 256 decimation rate
        BITS_12 = 3  // 12 bits resolution, 512 decimation rate
    };

    ADC(const Channel & channel = SINGLE_ENDED_ADC5, const Reference & reference = SYSTEM_REF, const Resolution & resolution = BITS_12)
    : _channel(channel), _reference(reference), _resolution(resolution) {
        Machine_Model::adc_config(_channel);
    }

    short read() {
        reg(ADCCON3) = (_reference * ADCCON3_EREF) | (_resolution * ADCCON3_EDIV) | (_channel * ADCCON3_ECH);
        while(!(reg(ADCCON1) & ADCCON1_EOC));
        short ret = (reg(ADCH) << 8) + reg(ADCL);
        switch(_resolution) {
            case BITS_7:  ret >>= 9; break;
            case BITS_9:  ret >>= 7; break;
            case BITS_10: ret >>= 6; break;
            case BITS_12: ret >>= 4; break;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    // returns the voltage corresponding to the reading, with three decimal places (e.g. 2534 means 2.534V)
    int convert(short raw_reading, int reference = 3300/*3.3V*/) {
        int limit;
        switch(_resolution) {
            case BITS_7:  limit =   63; break;
            case BITS_9:  limit =  255; break;
            case BITS_10: limit =  511; break;
            case BITS_12: limit = 2047; break;
        }
        return raw_reading * reference / limit;
    }

private:
    volatile CPU::Reg32 & reg(unsigned int o) { return reinterpret_cast<volatile CPU::Reg32*>(ADC_BASE)[o / sizeof(CPU::Reg32)]; }

    Channel _channel;
    Reference _reference;
    Resolution _resolution;
};

__END_SYS

#endif
```

error:

> temperature.cc: In function 'int main()': temperature.cc:11: error:
>   invalid conversion from 'int' to 'EPOS::S::ADC::Channel'
>   temperature.cc:11: error:   initializing argument 1 of
>   'EPOS::S::ADC::ADC(const EPOS::S::ADC::Channel&, const
>   EPOS::S::ADC::Reference&, const EPOS::S::ADC::Resolution&)'
>   temperature.cc:11: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to
>   'EPOS::S::ADC::Reference' temperature.cc:11: error:   initializing
>   argument 2 of 'EPOS::S::ADC::ADC(const EPOS::S::ADC::Channel&, const
>   EPOS::S::ADC::Reference&, const EPOS::S::ADC::Resolution&)'
>   temperature.cc:11: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to
>   'EPOS::S::ADC::Resolution' temperature.cc:11: error:   initializing
>   argument 3 of 'EPOS::S::ADC::ADC(const EPOS::S::ADC::Channel&, const
>   EPOS::S::ADC::Reference&, const EPOS::S::ADC::Resolution&)'
>   makefile:11: recipe for target 'temperature.o' failed make[2]: ***
>   [temperature.o] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/thiago/Documents/arm/app' makefile:17: recipe for target 'app'
>   failed make[1]: *** [app] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/thiago/Documents/arm' makefile:11: recipe for target 'all'
>   failed make: *** [all] Error 2

Programming language: c++

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use heap allocation on a Cortex M. Mainly because [it doesn't make any sense](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171257/realloc-wasting-lots-of-space-in-my-mcu/171581#171581). Also, don't use global variables. Also, don't return from main() in a freestanding system, return to what?

Comment: @Lundin I agree, but using [tag:c++] there are not many chances: you must use new keyword. BTW using dynamic allocation only for class instantiation at startup it is very near to static allocation, as far as you are correctly profiling your memory

Comment: @LPs You should be able to write C++ code without dynamic allocation. If not, then simply throw it out and write in C. And if you never intend to delete or re-allocate objects, you should obviously not use dynamic allocation. If you only allocate objects at start-up and never touch them, then the difference is that static allocation takes up exactly as much space as needed, where dynamic allocation takes up x amount of kb, which is the fixed heap size. So it is a huge waste of memory, for no gain.

Answer (score 0):

The ADC constructor wants 3 [parameters passed by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/), so you must pass variables.

Your code should be, at least:

```
int main(void)
{  
   Channel channel = TEMPERATURE; 
   Reference reference = SYSTEM_REF;
   Resolution resolution = BITS_12;

   temperature = new ADC( channel, reference, resolution);

   return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

As already said by other users, you shoud avoid to use dynamic allocation on embedded application with uC with limitated resources (RAM mainly).

So you can instantiate your class like:

```
int main(void)
{  
   short temperature;

   Channel channel = TEMPERATURE; 
   Reference reference = SYSTEM_REF;
   Resolution resolution = BITS_12;

   ADC reader( channel, reference, resolution);

   while (1)
   {
      temperature = reader.read();
   }
}
```

Comment: And then you need to call `temperature = reader.read();` preferably in a loop.